# Android place ImageView on top of Canvas

Tags: android, layout, canvas, android-imageview, android-drawable

how can I display a programmatically created ImageView on top of a previously created View Canvas? I tried using bringToFront(), but without success.

Code:

```
RelativeLayout root = findViewById(R.id.layout);
ImageView img = new ImageView(GameGuessActivity.context);
img.setImageResource(R.drawable.image);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width, height);
params.leftMargin = x;
params.topMargin = y;
root.addView(img, params);
img.bringToFront();
```

The Image is being displayed, but underneath the canvas, which I don't want.

Comment: hi Broadwell...did you got soltion for this? if so plz can you write that code as answer,it will be helpfull for me bcz i am not getting wt Pospai has written

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to redraw your imageview on canvas:

```
  pcanvas = new Canvas();
        pcanvas.setBitmap(bitmap);    // drawXY will result on that Bitmap
        pcanvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null); 
        mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC));
        image.draw(pcanvas);

        img.bringToFront();
        img.invalidate();
        img.draw(pcanvas);
```