# create ImageView programatically and draw on canvas android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, canvas, opengl-es

How can I create an ImageView programmatically and draw on canvas in Android?

I also saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29307102/android-place-imageview-on-top-) of-canvas  and tried the below code:

```
 ImageView img = new ImageView(HighScore.ctx);
    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.interactive);
    img.draw(canvas);
    img.bringToFront();
    img.invalidate();
    img.draw(canvas);
```

But the answer doesn't seem complete, it's not working. plz can anybody help me..

Answer (score 1):

Refer to this link: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#lattrs
Here equivalent methods of xml attributes for imageview are given.

Comment: hi thanks for ur replay but i didnt got solution from that URL :(

Comment: Its ok i hope you find it soon